# Github logs for fetch/pull requests

Tags: github, logging

I'm looking for similar traces to the ones can be retrieved from the command "git log --stat" but not for commits or merges but for fetches/pulls. Does anyone know if traces like that exist? and if yes is there any way for me to retrieve such information, when I don't own the repository?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

From what I know:

- `git fetch` doesn't leave any trace in the logs of a Git repo
- `git pull` could be guessed from the merges you can see from other branches from the namespace "remotes" of a repo
- `git pull --rebase` wouldn't be so easy to find back (since you rewrite the history of a local branch by rebasing it on top of a remotes branch)

The only thing you can list, for a GitHub repo, is the [list of pending pull requests with the GitHub V3 API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/).

```
GET /repos/:user/:repo/pulls
```